# SQL select from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My first table is as below (not important):

**tbl_Item**

```
ItemId,ItemName
1     ,'test'
2     ,'test2'
3     , 'test3'
```

and second table is (Important table),this table tell us that `ItemId` has what specifications? For example `ItemId` 1 has specs 5 and 6 and 7

**tbl_Spec**

```
ItemId , SpecId
1      ,5
1      ,6
1      ,7
2      ,5
2      ,8
3      ,5
3      ,7
```

How can I select Items that have both SpecId 5 and 7

the result must be :

```
ItemId
1
3
```

SQL In (...) do the OR as default, but I want something with And Function.

My DBMS is SQL Server 2008

Comment: What rules are supposed to be used in order to get the result? I don't see a direct connection from your data.

Comment: I want the Item Id to have both Specification 5 and 7. Item Id 2 just have 5 , but ItemId 1 and 3 , have both 5 and 7 in their values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there must be more elegant ways, but this should give you what you want (EDIT: fixed as per Michaeł Powaga's suggestion).

```
SELECT ItemId
FROM tbl_Spec
WHERE SpecId=5 OR SpecId=7
GROUP BY ItemId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT SpecId)=2
```

p.s. Ali , if you need a more easily expandable solution, have you seen Mikael Eriksson's answer?

Comment: Thanks, but do you have an expandable solution ?

Comment: Nice, but I would change `having` to `HAVING COUNT(distinct SpecId)>1` just in case `SpecId=5` for same `ItemId` exists twice.

Comment: @AliRezza change `where` condition to `in (...)` and in `having` part put desired number of items for 2 might be `>= 2`, for 3 `>= 3` and so on.

Comment: Thanks Paolo , your solution is better , I changed it to Where SpecId in (5,7) ... . this is a part of more complex query , And using this way is better for me than Other ways.

Answer (score 3):

```
select itemid from
(
    select itemid from tbl_spec where specid = 5
) subset1 inner join
(
    select itemid from tbl_spec where itemid = 7
) subset2 on subset1.itemid = subset2.itemid
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you have an expandable solution ?

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @T table
(
  ItemId int,
  SpecId int
)

insert into @T values
(1      ,5),
(1      ,6),
(1      ,7),
(2      ,5),
(2      ,5),
(2      ,8),
(3      ,5),
(3      ,7),
(4      ,5),
(4      ,5)

;with C(SpecId) as
(
  select 5 union all
  select 7
)
select T.ItemId
from @T as T
  inner join C
    on T.SpecId = C.SpecId
group by T.ItemId
having count(distinct T.SpecId) = (select count(*) from C)
```

Result:

```
ItemId
1
3
```

Comment: Thanks dear Mikael for your solution, yours is good,but because of the fact that this query is a part of more complex query, I Accepted the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will give the desired output you requested, but I'm not 100% sure if this is what you are asking for.

```
select distinct itemID
from tbl_Spec
where SpecId in (5,7)
```

Comment: I want it to have both 5 and 7 , not only one of them,I changed the question sample,and added ItemId2,5 .

Comment: You want what to have both 5 and 7? The query above will give you your requested resultset.

Comment: your query also returns ItemId 2 which I don't want.

Comment: Sorry, yes, misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following sql query

select ItemId from tbl_Spec where SpecId in (5,7)

Comment: No , because Item 2 will be selected,and I dont want that. In(...) do the OR function , but I want and Function.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct ItemId from tbl_Item, tbl_Spec 
where tbl_Item.ItemId=tbl_Spec.ItemId 
and tbl_SPec.SpecId not in (select SpecId from tbl_Spec where SpecId not in (5,7))
```

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (select Count(ItemID)Counted from tbl_Spec where Itemid in (select Itemid  from tbl_Item )and SpecId in(5,7) group by ItemID) a where Counted>=2
```